How does this processing meet the company's legitimate interests?
To quote Bella_Blue's 2024-06-17 answer:

The objection to legitimate interests selection does not apply to “Necessary cookies only” due to the ‘strictly necessary’ exemption. When the “Necessary cookies only” option is selected, it does not object to legitimate interest processing. An objection to legitimate interests requests clear affirmative action, as is dictated by TCF 2.2.

TCF 2.2 isn't the law; in fact, it often conflicts with the law. To quote the UK's ICO:

You should be careful not to confuse processing that is necessary for your stated purpose with processing which is only necessary because of your chosen method of pursuing that purpose. In the context of legitimate interests, you may be able to argue that some non-essential features of your processing (such as profiling or marketing) are necessary for your purposes. However, this is only the case if you clearly identify the specific purpose behind those particular features, and don’t hide behind a vague business objective that could be achieved in another way. The processing must be necessary for the specific purpose you have identified in step one. This is one reason why it is important to be clear and specific about your purposes.

To quote the "consent" modal itself:

Understand audiences through statistics or combinations of data from different sources
2 partners can use this purpose
Reports can be generated based on the combination of data sets (like user profiles, statistics, market research, analytics data) regarding your interactions and those of other users with advertising or (non-advertising) content to identify common characteristics (for instance, to determine which target audiences are more receptive to an ad campaign or to certain contents).
Illustrations
The owner of an online bookstore wants commercial reporting showing the proportion of visitors who consulted and left its site without buying, or consulted and bought the last celebrity autobiography of the month, as well as the average age and the male/female distribution of each category. Data relating to your navigation on its site and to your personal characteristics is then used and combined with other such data to produce these statistics.

This looks like hiding behind “a vague business objective that could be achieved in another way” to me. Of course, that's because I'm uninformed. But, to quote the UK's ICO again:

If you are unable to demonstrate that the processing actually helps meet the legitimate interest, then you are not able to apply this basis.

The company claims the legitimate interest basis for unspecified processing under:

Functional: "Link different devices"

"4 partners can use this purpose"


Performance: "Develop and improve services"

"3 partners can use this purpose"


Performance: "Measure content performance"

"0 partners can use this purpose"
I think I know what this refers to, and that's actually legitimate if I'm right.


Performance: "Measure advertising performance"

"5 partners can use this purpose"


Targeting: "Understand audiences through statistics or combinations of data from different sources"

"2 partners can use this purpose"


Targeting: "Use limited data to select advertising"

"4 partners can use this purpose"
Seems like a mixture of legitimate ("to limit the number of times an ad is presented to you") and illegitimate ("your non-precise location, your device type or which content you are (or have been) interacting with"); not sure which are supposed to be covered under "legitimate interest".



The "partners" are:

BeeswaxIO Corporation (13 months)
Xandr, Inc. (a Microsoft subsiduary) (3 months)
Rockerbox, Inc (< 1 Day)
Commanders Act (12 months)

This one doesn't claim legitimate interest.


Google Advertising Products (13 months)

Please demonstrate, as required, how each claimed "legitimate interest" meets the company's legitimate interests. 

FYI Based on previous interactions, I doubt that there will be any response anytime soon. However https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy contains a segment on "legitimate interests". Though I find it is quite nonspecific (no concrete cookies/tracking techniques are mentioned) and overall it reads like a copy & paste of some generic blueprint. (Also if you go by the letter of the law in this document it only speaks of SOs own interests and not that of third parties, due to how "We" is defined.)

@A-Tech If you go by the letter of the law, SO's own interests are the only thing that's allowed to be a "legitimate interest". "Somebody else is paying us" is not a legitimate interest; nor is "it's only polite to let this other unrelated organisation get some benefit from our users".

what's the time duration next to each partner?

@JourneymanGeek I don't know. It says "Lifespan" and "This vendor utilizes other methods of storage or accessing information in addition to cookies.", but that doesn't mean much.

@wizzwizz4 retention time maybe? For example "BeeswaxIO Corporation (13 months)" would mean that BeeswaxIO  stores the info up to 13 months from the collection date

@ꓢPArcheon Yes, that would be the sensible thing to write. But I suspect it's cookie duration, and information about retention is left unspecified. (e.g. iirc Google's data retention is 18 months, and their inference retention is unlimited.)

How close are we to having a basis for a class action lawsuit?

@KarlKnechtel Stack Exchange is more sue-able than most companies, because they're more transparent; but they're not the biggest (or, in this case, primary) offenders. The Interactive Advertising Bureau is a much better target for your ire, I think. Thinking strategically, I don't think transparency is something we want to be punishing with legal threats.

@wizzwizz4 problem is, if this is how transparency looks like (ie: a bunch of text that is almost but not completely unlike an informative note) this is less about transparency and more about smoke&mirrors. See your other posts about the cookie purposes.
